# Solution for writing a program for keep secret photos

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image

Solution for writing a program for keep  secret photos.

I have many secret photos of me and my friends and I don't want anyone to see it
for now I just use 
     Winrar and Set password feature and use some encrypt and hide folder software.
But I think it isn't enough safe.

As I am a C# programmer ,I want to develop an application for do it.

- I want to know a solution for encrypt and decrypt file.
- Do I need to write viewer application ? If I view them via ACSSee or other program I fear it will cache my file.
- As I know when we write "File.Delete()" it isn't real delete,any one can recovery it.How I make sure that my application really delete it (What about modify data and make it cannot use before delete it) ?

FYI

- My pc doesn't connect to the internet and I bought it for keep,view my photos only I don't want to do other thing.
- If my pc was break I will not sent it to anyone for repair it.
- I am only one who use it.

**Update**

My photo is just shame photos. 
Actually I just want to know how to do that and something i wrote it is just "suppose"

such as "I bought it for keep,view my photos only I don't want to do other thing."

It is so weird if I spent 400$ for do something like that.
I though everyone will know it is just kidding.
sorry for made this question not clear.

I just want to know how someone hack it in this situation.And how to protect them by C# language.

Comment: You state:  
> My pc doesn't connect to the internet  

and  

> I am only one who use it.  

So what are you worried about? WinRAR can do encryption too if that is what you are looking for. Windows also has folder encryption. Vista has bit locker which is even more advanced.

Comment: Is it just me, or does this sound as hinky as hell?

Comment: If you're worried about people recovering data from deleted files on the hard disk of a computer that only you have access to, isn't online and was bought specifically for keeping said photos on, I have to wonder what kind of dodgy photos you're trying to hide...

Comment: @Binary Worrier:  It's just you, sounds "dodgy" as hell to me.

Comment: I know someone that works as a code breaker for our national police force, they've yet to give her a cache of photographs she couldn't access. I think you need help of a different kind than you'll find on SO

Comment: You and your friends? auhehuaue sounds legal enought for me..

Comment: What ever you do with those pictures, STOP!. Having pictures that are *that* big of a secret, is not good, you either are a spy, a perv, a child molester, a thief, or something bad ... I think you need to ask not how I can keep them secret, but where should I get therapy.

Comment: Thank you for yours answer

But I wonder ,Is my question ilegal for SO why I got many downvotes.


@ninesided "I have to wonder what kind of dodgy photos you're trying to hide"

I got dressed like Japan rock band.

Comment: @ash: In my personal lexicon hinky = dodgy, only more so

Comment: @Krirk an "illegal" question would be closed by someone with enough rights to do so. Downvotes are because people find your question "not useful" or "not clear".

Comment: @Daniel daranas


I am sorry that my question is not clear

As @ Robert MacLean answer I though Winrar is safe enough.
I might too worry.

O.K. thank you everyone :)

Comment: @Pop Catalin.  Or he lives in a represive society where a picture of something we think of as harmless could land you in prison.

Comment: @Martin: I hadn't thought of that. Krirk, in any western country your request makes you sound like a Paedophile. Apologies if I have wrongfully maligned you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Someone already wrote it : [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)

Encrypt your entire PC or a folder - your choice.

Answer (score 3):

as already mentioned just use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).

But let me try to find out why you got all these downvotes.

You wrote that you have some secret stuff on your PC that nobody has to find out, but you are the only user of the pc and it isn't connected to the internet.

So you have already done enough to hide your secret. Surely someone can break into your house and steal the pc. But that's no pc problem. It's a security problem of your house.

And the style what you're asking about encrypting and decrypting it sounds that you have absoluty no clue about how to write a software in such a way that your data is really protected. So do you really want to write your own cypher algorithm? As already proved by dozens of other programmers it is not possible to write a secure code by yourself.

So if you need some 'real' secure solution to lock some drive or folder just TrueCrypt, because the really know how to secure data with proven algorithm and with minimal traces on your pc.

And just another mark: If you had just clearly written your question like 'How can i securely lock a folder on my pc so that nobody can access the data within?' you add achieve the same answers without any downvotes. Believe me. ;-)

Best regards,

Oliver

Comment: 'How can i securely lock a folder on my pc so that nobody can access the data within?' <-- I agree with you it is better.

Answer (score 2):

Truecrypt as mentioned above is the one thing you want. Its opensource i think, so no backdoor solutions (no mr FBI coming getting your dirty stuff!).

Regarding files being temped to c:\temp make sure you use a viewer that does not cache the images or part of the images to disk.

Irfanview/Xnview?  ( I use those in combination with Total Commander ).

Answer (score 1):

I only have an answer for the other side of your situation: [Know your enemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_forensics).